# Adjunction arrows

Tags: math-mode

I would like to draw adjunction arrows in LaTeX, i.e. something like this:

[image]

Possibly, I would also like to be able to name the arrows (but I can use \stackrel or similar, if not). Is there a package containing this symbol somewhere?

Comment: I know of only the arrows (`\rightleftharpoons`) but with that `_|_` in the middle, never seen it. Also [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) didn't find it.

Comment: Some like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
$F:C\stackrel[^\leftharpoondown]{_\rightharpoonup}{{\scriptscriptstyle \perp}}O:G$
\end{document}` ?

Comment: @Fran Looks promising, but it gives me some errors, and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud  For some unknown reason, when pasted, a "zero with space" was inserted in the comment inside `\scriptscriptstyle` (in the  second "sc"). Just remove it  and it should work.

Comment: @Fran Oh, weird! Ok, it works now, but it is not typesetted the way I would like it to look. No offense, but I'll stick to egreg's answer for now.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud None taken. It is a great answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possibility, with a very small symbol in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\adjunction}[4]{%
  % #1 : #2 <arrows> #3 : #4
  #1\colon #2%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil$##$\hfil\cr
      \longrightharpoonup\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \smallbot\cr
      \longleftharpoondown\cr
    }%
  }}%
  #3 \noloc #4%
}
\newcommand{\longrightharpoonup}{\relbar\joinrel\rightharpoonup}
\newcommand{\longleftharpoondown}{\leftharpoondown\joinrel\relbar}
\newcommand\noloc{%
  \nobreak
  \mspace{6mu plus 1mu}
  {:}
  \nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip
  \mathpunct{}
  \mspace{2mu}
}
\newcommand{\smallbot}{%
  \begingroup\setlength\unitlength{.15em}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline(0,0)(1,0)
  \polyline(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\adjunction{F}{\mathcal{C}}{\mathcal{D}}{G}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version where you can choose, with `\adjunction*`, to place the labels above and below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\adjunction}{\@ifstar\named@adjunction\normal@adjunction}
\newcommand{\normal@adjunction}[4]{%
  % #1 : #2 <arrows> #3 : #4
  #1\colon #2%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil$##$\hfil\cr
      \longrightharpoonup\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \smallbot\cr
      \longleftharpoondown\cr
    }%
  }}%
  #3 \noloc #4%
}
\newcommand{\named@adjunction}[4]{%
  % #1 : #2 <arrows> #3 : #4
  #2%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{%
      \hfil$##$\hfil\cr
      \scriptstyle#1\cr
      \noalign{\kern.1ex}
      \longrightharpoonup\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \smallbot\cr
      \longleftharpoondown\cr
      \scriptstyle#4\cr
    }%
  }}%
  #3%
}
\newcommand{\longrightharpoonup}{\relbar\joinrel\rightharpoonup}
\newcommand{\longleftharpoondown}{\leftharpoondown\joinrel\relbar}
\newcommand\noloc{%
  \nobreak
  \mspace{6mu plus 1mu}
  {:}
  \nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip
  \mathpunct{}
  \mspace{2mu}
}
\newcommand{\smallbot}{%
  \begingroup\setlength\unitlength{.15em}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline(0,0)(1,0)
  \polyline(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\adjunction{F}{\mathcal{C}}{\mathcal{D}}{G}
\]
\[
\adjunction*{F}{\mathcal{C}}{\mathcal{D}}{G}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your remarkable (and pretty long, I'd say) work! It's a shame that the symbol in the middle is so small, but it's true that it's basically impossible to make it bigger without putting the arrows too far apart. Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud As you observed, making the symbol larger would mean pushing the harpoons too far apart, unless a different arrow tip style is adopted. The code is long, but I already had some similar code, so writing the main part was easy and only testing it was reeded.

Comment: Anyway, I greatly appreciate the effort. I will certainly us it, and I think that other people will, when they see it.