# Spacing in \colon

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas) the consistent way to write a function is `f\colon A\to B`, but if I want to write a cospan like the following

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\(0\colon 1\to I\leftarrow 1\colon 1\)
\end{document}
```

it gives this result[image]
in which the second `\colon` has not the correct spacing. So, is there a way to be consistent with the document and have correct spacing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\noloc` command I defined for [a similar purpose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332088/4427)

```latex
\newcommand\noloc{%
  \nobreak
  \mspace{6mu plus 1mu}
  {:}
  \nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip
  \mathpunct{}
  \mspace{2mu}
}
```

[image]

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\noloc{%
  \nobreak
  \mspace{6mu plus 1mu}
  {:}
  \nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip
  \mathpunct{}
  \mspace{2mu}
}

\begin{document}

\(0\colon 1\to I\leftarrow 1\noloc 1\)

\end{document}
```